# peerdependencies & dependencies when packaging angular library using nx

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, nrwl-nx

In my nx mono repo, I created multiple libraries (more than 30), most of them are publishable and there are dependencies with each other.

I've seen a lot of problems when we migrated from node 14 to 16, because of the way node manage the node_modules.

I would like to package my libraries in a way NX will set

- as **peerDeps** all the libraries that come from outside of my repo (like angular/core, CDK, material ...).
- as **dependencies** repo libraries (if my library B needs library A it will be defined as a dependency).

In that way, if someone need one of my library he will have to install only one library (others will be installed automatically and it won't crash for different versions of angular or any third part library)